# Laravel payments methods with debit and credit cards

Tags: laravel

I need some packages about Laravel payments with debit and credit carts. Is there any learning, packages, tutorials, YouTube video or websites to learn this problems or not? help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This is off topic because it is not about coding, but seeking for libraries and software tips. SO is not the correct place for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to choose from.

You can use `Paypal` though if you haven't used any payment package before this might not be a straight forwar one. There's another one called `omnipay`.

OR

You can use Laravel Cashier which is Laravel official Package and documentation is quite detailed as well.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing